# Where is the smtp configuration in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my project (codeigniter) how can I find out SMTP details? I found in config folder in that email.php. It contains like this

How can I find out `SMTP_SERVER`, `SMTP_USER`. Could please help me on this.

```
$config = array(
"mailtype"      => "html",
"protocol"      => EMAIL_PROTOCOL,
"smtp_host"     => SMTP_SERVER,
"smtp_user"     => SMTP_USER,
"smtp_pass"     => SMTP_PASS,
"crlf"          => "\n",
"newline"       => "\r\n"
);
```

Comment: you can get it from mail service provider. `SMTP_USER and SMTP_PASS` are your normal login credentials.

Comment: it looks like global variables, have you tried looking at `application/config/constants.php`

Comment: yes i tried but there is no smtp details on constacts.php page

Answer (score 0):

There is no default config file for SMTP settings in codeigniter. But, you can create your own config file to set these values globally. Here is an excerpt from codeigniter user guide:

> Setting Email Preferences in a Config File
>
> If you prefer not to set preferences using the above method, you can instead put them into a config file. Simply create a new file called the email.php, add the $config array in that file. Then save the file at config/email.php and it will be used automatically. You will NOT need to use the $this->email->initialize() function if you save your preferences in a config file.

Comment: that is not the point OP already has email config, what the OP wants is where the globals `SMTP_SERVER` `SMTP_USER` located on his code, obviously the program is not his

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I totally missed that part. In that case he can check the constants.php file as you mentioned. But I doubt he has modified constants.php if he has taken code from somewhere else. On a side note, a simple search of the keyword in his source code / IDE will tell if the constant is there or not. :)

Comment: That's fine but now i want to change my smtp server details.so where is SMTP_SERVER url is stored or in which file it is stored.

Comment: you need to check with whatever SMTP service you are using. e.g. google/amazon provides SMTP services to send mails for websites. Are you using any such service?

Comment: yes that is i'm finding(SMTP_SERVER) details.Where smtp details stored in site

Comment: which smtp service are you using?

Comment: For gmail following are the settings which you can store in config/email.php file:
$config = Array(
      'protocol' => 'smtp',
      'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
      'smtp_port' => 465,
      'smtp_user' => '<test-account-name>@gmail.com',
      'smtp_pass' => '<test-account-password>',
    );